# Recursive rm doesn't work for me

Tags: rm, recursive

Suppose, we have the following files in a directory:

```
test.txt
test.txt~
/subdir
  test1.txt
  test1.txt~
```

When I run `rm -r ./*.*~` inside top dir only test.txt~ is removed.

Why doesn't it perform the recursive removal despite the fact that I used recursive flag?

You can reproduce my case with the following script:

```
#create dir and 1-st level test files
mkdir dir
cd dir
touch test.txt
touch test.txt~

#create subdir and 2-nd level test files
mkdir subdir
cd subdir/
touch test1.txt~
touch test1.txt

cd ..
rm -r ./*.*~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*.*~` does not expand to any directories, it will just match any file or directory in the current directory that has a `.` in it somewhere and ends in `~`

If you would like to find all the files that end in `~` from the directory you're in I would use `find` like

```
find -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `rm -r *.*~` (same as `rm -r ./*.*~`) would remove files and directories matching `*.*~` that is files and directories whose name contain a dot and ends with a `~`

But `subdir` doe not contain any dot, so does not fit.

Read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and remember that it is your shell (not the `/bin/rm` program!) which does the [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globbing).

So what is happening is that you type `rm -r ./*.*~` to your shell. Your shell is expanding that to `rm -r ./test.txt~`; then it finds the `/bin/rm` program in your `$PATH`, calls [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a child process, and then [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) on `/bin/rm` program, with an argument array of `rm -rf ./test.txt~` so `rm` does not even see `./subdir`

To have every backup file removed in any direct subdirectory, type `rm */*.*~`; with *recent* `bash` (version 4 or later) and `zsh` you could remove any backup file even deep in the file tree with `rm **/*.*`

A possible way to understand what the shell is doing is to replace your command (e.g. `rm`) with `echo`. That should give you the expansion (but read [echo(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html), since `echo` is understanding some options like `-n`). On some good shells, you could even use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key for [autocompletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). I'm using [zsh](http://zsh.org/) as my interactive shell because I like its autocompletion features.

At last, [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) knows about `-i` (asking you interactively before removal). So I'll suggest `rm -i **/*~`

BTW, if you don't know about version control systems, it is time to learn them (I strongly recommend using [git](http://git-scm.com/)....), especially for "source" code like files (C or Python programs, shell scripts, etc etc etc ...) and you won't need backup files.

Comment: I use git. Emacs creates backup files on it's own. And I don't want to disable it, cause there were cases when I had to use them.

Comment: Mine bash is 4.2.53 but `rm -r **.*~` didn't remove subdir/test1.txt~

Comment: You forgot a `/`; I am suggesting `rm **/*~`

Comment: `globstar` is a `zsh` feature adopted by `bash4` and `ksh`. In `bash` and `ksh` you must turn the feature on. For ` bash`  : `shopt -s globstar` and for `ksh` : `set -o globstar`