# Is `~/Documents` a relative or an absolute path?

Tags: shell, filenames

This is merely just a vocabulary question, but which keeps turning around in my head.

It comes from a practice exam from a [LPIC](https://www.lpi.org/certification/) preparation book. The correct answer according to the book is that `~/Documents` is a relative directory because it is relative to the home directory.

However, this book contains an honourable ratio of typos and mistakes so I cannot take for granted everything which is written there. Here I do not agree because for me `~` acts as a variable expanded by the shell into either the content of the `$HOME` variable or the current user home directory path (cf. [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)), so the actual path is `/home/myuser/Documents` which is indeed an absolute directory.

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths), for once, seems of no help to me on this topic (even if it seems to confirm that the book is wrong on this one):

> An absolute or full path points to the same location in a file system
>   regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must
>   contain the root directory.
>
> By contrast, a relative path starts from some given working directory,
>   avoiding the need to provide the full absolute path.

Here again, I do not agree: according to this definition, the path `/opt/kde3/bin/../lib` which does not depends of the current working directory should be an absolute one, however my current understanding of this matches the book's author making this path a relative one.

A quick web-search is just adding to my frustration, according to [Webster Dictionary](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/absolute%20path):

> **absolute path** - A path relative to the root directory. Its first character must be the pathname separator.

So `$HOME/Documents`, or even just `$HOME` would not be considered absolute directories? Or does this definition implies variable expansion? What about the shell's `~` character? Is there any reliable definition of relative vs. absolute directory I can find somewhere and am I wrong all of the way?

Comment: All paths are relative, some of them are just relative only to the root directory `/`, and those we call absolute. Thus everything what starts from `/` I would call absolute (even if this is `/usr/../etc`) and everything else I would call relative (`~/Doc`, `Doc`, `../john/Doc`, `$HOME/...`,...). The point is that absolute should work regardless of current working directory or current user. Relative can work only in some specific narrow cases.

Comment: The path could expand to a different location depending on who the user is. Having said that, this is still an absolute path, not a relative path, in my opinion. Though I don't think the definitions of absolute and relative path are so precisely defined. This isn't mathematics. This question doesn't really test understanding, imo, and is pointless.

Comment: @jimmij I did not see a dependence on the current user in Wikipedia or other pages I've visited, only to the current working directory. Would this also make path depending on any other variable value to be relative (`$SOMEDIR/data`)? Or would it just be limited to `$HOME`, `$USER` and `$LOGNAME` variables because they are linked to the current user?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: "*Distinguishing the two is pointless*": I would gladly take this as an answer ;). It was at the University more than a dozen of years of Unixes ago last time I encountered them and it seemed quite clear at the time. Now that I'm passing certifications it is getting back with dubious examples...

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Ok, I posted my comment as an answer. I don't know what LPIC is, but if all the questions are like that, it doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf For me absolute path is path that starts from `/` so you can give any other user and it will work in all cases - that's why we call it **absolute** (true, full, complete, unlimited, authentic, entire, unconditional, you name it).

Comment: @FaheemMitha: [LPIC](https://www.lpi.org/certification/) is a distribution neutral Linux certification. The certification itself seems fine, but this is far from being the case about (at least some) books sold to prepare for this exam as self-study...

Comment: @jimmij: "relative" has a specific technical meanings in the context of paths, and using a different English-language sense of the word is bad practice.  I totally disagree with calling `~/foo` a relative path.  What you're getting at is the difference between hard-coding and parameterization.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: It could be a relative path if the `HOME` environment variable contained a relative path. But putting a relative path in `HOME` is asking for trouble.

Comment: The Webster Dictionary's definitions is correct, but very confusing. However, it implies that strings such as `~/Documents` and `$HOME/Documents` are not paths. They do identify (absolute) paths after expansion, but they are not paths themselves. I think that agrees with how many Unix/Linux users use the term, but no doubt those strings are also called paths themselves.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If the author was trying to catch you out by talking about that literal string (without shell expansion) as a path, then it's a relative path (`mkdir -p './~/Documents'`).  Otherwise:

---

It's an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths), because resolving it doesn't depend on the process's current working directory.  *Relative path* always means relative to the process's working directory.  Or in the case of symlink targets, relative to the location of the symlink.  (`gcc -> gcc-5.2` vs. `gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc-5.2`).  This matters for NFS-mounts and other cases where you can get to the same symlink via different absolute paths.  e.g.

```
/net/tesla/home/peter/foo -> bar  # always works from other machines

/net/tesla/home/peter/foo -> /home/peter/bar  # references my home dir on the local machine, not tesla.
```

Debian will sometimes install symlinks to `../../doc/whatever/whatever`, instead of an absolute symlink target, so it works when NFS mounted somewhere else, or when looking at a chroot without `chroot(8)`ing into it.

Every Unix process has its own cwd.  The `pwd` command exists just to print it.

see:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html
for more about changing directories with POSIX system calls.

---

As everyone else has said, `~` is expanded by the shell before the path is used for anything.  Using `~/bin/myprog` in a shell script will make it work differently for different users.  The difference between `~/bin/foo` and `/home/peter/bin/foo` is that one of them has hard-coded the location, while the other has parameterized it.  It's an error (IMO) to call the `~` version a relative path.

Talking about things being "relative to an environment variable" is just confusing.  It's bad practice to use different English-language meanings of terms that have specific technical meanings in the context you're using them in.

On a broken system, with `HOME=a/relative/path`, `~/foo` would expand to a relative path.  This would not be a usable setup at all.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it seems to be the most comprehensive one to me. I have also the impression that the author wrongly mixed up the notion of *canonical path* into this (which the author do not mention anywhere). `/opt/kde3/bin/../lib` for instance is wrongly classified as a relative path: it *is* an absolute path but is *not* the canonical one. As you said, this just makes everything confusing, so thanks for your clarification and the info related to NFS :) !

Comment: I have to conclude that writing a test-prep book is not a lot of fun, and that people who just use Unix or GNU/Linux for their everyday computing aren't the ones writing those books.  That example of a calling a non-canononical path *relative* seems really bad and obvious to me.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html (and `realpath(1)`) do both things: canonicalize and make absolute (as well as follow symlinks), so possibly some confusion crept in there.

Comment: Still, those are just ordinary everyday concepts for me.  I think it'd be weird to have a piece of paper that said I knew them...  But good luck getting your piece of paper, @WhiteWinterWolf, to show to all the people that like to look at pieces of paper. :)

Answer (score 48):

This is essentially a question about the definition of terms. So for your purposes, the answer is whatever LPIC wants. But we can come to some conclusions based on technical facts:

If you passed `'~/Documents'` to a **system call**, it would look for a directory named exactly `~` in the current directory (and probably fail). So, by the notion of pathnames used by *the kernel*, this is a relative path — but that's not what we meant.

`~` is syntax implemented by *the shell* (and other programs which imitate it for convenience) which *expands* it into a real pathname. To illustrate, `~/Documents` is approximately the same thing as `$HOME/Documents` (again, shell syntax). Since `$HOME` should be an absolute path, *the value of* `$HOME/Documents` is also an absolute path. But the text `$HOME/Documents` or `~/Documents` has to be expanded by the shell in order to become the path we mean.

Thus if I wanted to be precise and consistent, I would say that `~/Documents` is **a fragment of shell-script which expands to an absolute path.**

Comment: Of course, the kernel would have no idea what `$HOME` means, just like it has no idea what `~` means. I do however find the claim that ~ expansion is done by the shell to be dubious; most applications support this, which points toward the C library rather than the shell. Environment variable expansion however *is* a feature of the shell; you can open `~/somefile.odt` in LibreOffice, but not `$HOME/somefile.odt`, even if LibreOffice was started from a shell within which $HOME is properly set.

Comment: You can find it dubious all you want, but it's [documented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion) and should be easy to confirm or disprove in C.

Comment: Other programs implement `~` syntax in imitation of the shell, because it's a useful shortcut. I don't actually know whether there's a library function that does the expansion, but it's definitely something that is done separately from actually using the pathname.

Comment: `glob` and `wordexp` do tilde expansion among other things.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: A few programs implement `~` expansion; most do not. For example, if you type `ls -l ~`, the `ls` program never sees the `~` character; it's expanded by the shell before `ls` is invoked. If you actually pass a `~` to `ls`, it won't treat it specially; try `ls -l '~`'` (which will try to list a file named literally `~`).

Comment: I think it's merely a problem to understand what the book's author had in mind merely than "*whatever LPIC wants*" (I just finished a third exam with them and their genuine exam questions makes by far more sense). I guess that the author was selected merely upon being low-cost (the cover do not mention any technical reviewer too) and ordered by the editor (unrelated to the LPIC organization itself) to finish the book faster, so he went a bit "free-style" sometimes. Nevertheless, for this one I felt I needed some external advices before claiming that the author was false, thanks :) !

Comment: I completely disagree with the statement that whatever definition of "absolute path" the author has provided, regardless of whether it defines how the term is used by everybody else, defines the right answer to this question. That clearly is not what is being asked here. And the author's use of the term is simply wrong. Yes, I can write a book that defines "Linux" as "Windows 8.1" but when somebody asks: is it really? the only correct answer is: no, it isn't.

Answer (score 15):

If your `$HOME` is `/home/white/`, `~/Documents` (same as `$HOME/Documents`) is expanded by the shell (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220835/50557) for an explanation) to `/home/white/Documents`, which is an *absolute* path.

A relative path is one that does not start with a `/` (after shell expansion), like `../Documents` or `foo/bar`

Some old shells don't expand `~` (the way `bash`, `tcsh`, `zsh`, etc. ... do); they would see `~/Documents` as a relative path starting with `~`; but you usually don't have directory name like `~` (but you might create one with `mkdir '~'`, which I don't recommend).

Comment: you should mention which shells dont expand `~`

Answer (score 3):

An *absolute path* starts at `/` (what it refers to is fixed), a *relative path* starts at the current directory (and so what it refers to changes as the current directory changes). Most shells use `~` at the beginning as an abbreviation for the absolute path to the home directory of the current user, i.e., `~/Documents` is the directory `Documents` in the home of the current user, regardless of what the current directory might be. So it is an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

The path could expand to a different location depending on who the user is. Having said that, this is still an absolute path, not a relative path, in my opinion. However, I don't think the definitions of absolute and relative path are so precisely defined. This isn't mathematics. This question doesn't really test understanding, in my opinion, and is pointless.

Comment: The definition is a lot more than opinion.  Wikipedia takes a stab at it for the general case, not just Unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Answer (score 1):

The use of the ~/ at the beginning makes the path absolute since (by any definition) being able to find documents does not depend on where you currently are. However the expansion is done by the shell, not the kernel, so if you are using a shell that does not recognise this syntax ( such as /bin/sh, the original Bourne shell, not the bash alias ), you will be out of luck.

Interestingly, if you use ~root/ rather than ~/, the optimisation of reading $HOME typically does not apply and it will always resolve to an absolute if /etc/passwd is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The book seems to be taking the view that an absolute path is any path beginning with a `/`, and a relative path is anything else.

You might view `..` and `$HOME` as similar types of tokens. Both need to be substituted, for a path component, before the path resolves to an absolute path.

Comment: How is `..` anything like `$HOME`?  `..` can be at the start of a path passed directly to a system call, no shell expansion required.  Such a path is *not* an absolute path; it's still relative to the process cwd or symlink location.  Unless the author was trying to catch you out by talking about that literal string (without shell expansion) as a path.  I think you're trying to make excuses for the book, but I'm more inclined to just say it's wrong and not let things get muddled.