# Is ~/Mary a relative path?

Tags: directory, syntax

Let's suppose `Mary` is a directory. Is the following path `~/Mary` relative?

Comment: Similar: [Path syntax rules](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/125522)

Comment: I would describe the "Mary" part as being relative to the (context dependent) tilde (~) part.

Comment: As an aside, a path does not have to point to a directory so assuming `Mary` to be a directory in not needed for your question.

Comment: If you are related to Mary then it is a path to your relative ...

Comment: @StephenG That's like saying all paths are relative… to `/`.

Comment: @sparhawk No it's not, because the tilde part is context dependent (a variable, in effect).  That's why it's so useful.  Certainly ~/Mary is not an absolute path, because in a different process it can have a different resolved path.  Indeed, you can alter the HOME variable in a script and get two different results in the same process for this path.

Answer (score 75):

No, it's not relative.

It's a full path, with `~` being an alias.

Relative paths describe a path in relation to your current directory location.  However, `~/Mary` is exactly the same, no matter which directory you're currently in.

Assuming you were currently logged in as *Bob* and also in the directory `/home/Bob`, then `../Mary` would be an example of a relative path to `/home/Mary`.  If you were currently in `/etc/something` then `~/Mary` would still be `/home/Bob/Mary` but `../Mary` would now be `/etc/Mary`.

Note that Bash handles `~` in particular ways, and that it doesn't always translate to `$HOME`.

For further reading, see

- [Why doesn't the tilde (~) expand inside double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes)
- [The POSIX standard on tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)
- [The Bash manual on tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)

Comment: `../Mary` in `/home/Bob` would not refer to `/home/Bob/Mary`, it would refer to `/home/Mary`. Perhaps you meant to write `/home/Bob/something`?

Comment: I would avoid calling `~` an alias; that name is already taken. Rather, it is simply a token that is part of a different shell feature, tilde expansion. Aside from `~` alone and `~user`, there are also absolute and relative directory stack expressions like `~+`, `~-`, `~2`, `~+1`, `~-3`, etc.

Comment: @chepner I wonder if a user can name itself `2` on the system. If yes, then `~2` wouldn't work to go to that user's Home, right? Or would it?

Comment: @Cœur, all numeric user names would be a bad idea as several commands accept both username and userids in the same context (like `find -user 0`, `ps -u 0`...)

Comment: `~/Mary` is `/home/youruser/Mary`, `~Mary` is `/home/Mary`.

Comment: `~` was probably chosen because it was easy to type on a US keyboard.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Which US keyboard? Aside from the alphanumeric keys, keyboard layouts in the 80s and earlier were not very standardized.

Comment: @chepner yes, I struggled to find a word other than alias that made for easy reading.

Comment: Thanks all for correcting my stupid mistakes (while I slept!)

Comment: @EightBitTony Your edit was correct, as Kroltan already commented. I reverted the last edit.

Comment: If you're in `/home/Bob` then `../Mary` is `/home/Mary`, *not* `/home/Bob/Mary`. The relative path to `/home/Bob/Mary` from `/home/Bob` would be `./Mary`, or just `Mary`.

Comment: @BobJarvis Darn, yes. Thrown the baby out with the bath water. For user `Bob` from `/home/Bob`, a `../Mary`  would be `/home/Mary`, but a `~/Mary` would be `/home/Bob/Mary`. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: @8bittree I could not locate an image of a PDP-7 keyboard.

Answer (score 50):

If that `~/Mary` is a path given to any system call (like `open()`,`stat()`...), then it's  a relative path, it's the `Mary` entry related to the `~` directory in the current directory. So if your current directory is `/tmp` for instance, that will be the `/tmp/~/Mary` file.

However, if that `~/Mary` is used unquoted in a shell (or other tool) that supports tilde expansion, then that `~` will be substituted with the content of the `$HOME` variable (if it's set), and as `$HOME` typically contains an absolute path like `/home/me`, `~/Mary` will be expanded to `/home/me/Mary`, so an absolute path as well.

If you change `$HOME` to be a relative path (but you wouldn't want to do that), then `~/Mary` would be expanded to a relative path by the shell:

```
$ HOME=..; echo ~/Mary
../Mary
```

If you change it to `//foo` (or if your home directory was `/` which used to be common for `root`), then the expansion of `~/Mary` would be neither an [*absolute pathname*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_02) nor a [*relative pathname*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324) (at least per the POSIX definitions).

With `bash` versions prior to 4.0, you could even do funny things like:

```
$ HOME='*' bash-3.2.48 -c 'cd /; echo ~/mount'
bin/mount run/mount
```

(that was fixed in 4.0)

More info on [Unix&Linux](/.) at

- [Does ~ always equal $HOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)
- [Path syntax rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125522)

Comment: Egads.  A relative `$HOME` like `HOME=..` is frightening.

Comment: @AdamKatz, what about a wildcard `$HOME` like `HOME='*'` (see edit) ;-)

Comment: Crazy values of `HOME`? So many things I wish I didn't know... 

Comment: Looks like `HOME=.` works too, and you can have a little fun with `HOME='~'; cd` generating an error like `bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory`.  Wow, this rabbit hole is deep...

Answer (score 7):

Lets get pedantic.

As others have stated, it is an alias; as such, it is strictly neither an absolute path nor a relative path. Practically, it is an absolute path as it is not relative to the working directory.

Now for the details.  At an OS level, aliases are not supported, so the rule that all absolute paths start with a slash holds true, and everything else is a relative path. However, applications might not just pass the name to the kernel: special handling of `:`, `~` and `-` is common and application dependent. `-` is used to start options so to ensure that you are using a relative path you can prepend `./` to force relative handling in almost all cases (as far as I know the sole exception is a hostname containing a slash in some implementations of `rcp` or `scp`).  Recognition of `:` is used in detecting urls and remote hosts for some commands and leading `//` also has special meaning in some cases, but all of these cases are application level issues not OS level.

Almost all shells (I know of one exception) and many Unix applications support basic tilde expansion. The two tilde expansions that are most likely to work are `~/path` (where the leading tilde is replaced with the contents of the `$HOME` variable), and `~name/path` (where `name` is looked up in the user data base to locate the user `name`'s home directory).  Where it gets funky is if the user data base does not contain absolute paths (don't do that) or `$HOME` does not contain an absolute path (don't do that either). Other forms of tilde expansion may also exist; for example, Bash expands `~-` to the previous working directory, again all at the application level (and the shell is an application).

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about that last part. `~-` is an alias for `$OLDPWD` and `~+N` and `~-N` can be used to get to the Nth positions from the top or bottom of the directory stack (as controlled by `pushd` and `popd`).  Search for `~-` in `man bash` or `man zshexpn` to learn more.

Comment: "Practically, it is an absolute path as it is not relative to the working directory". However, it is relative to the current user home directory. ~/Mary references a different absolute path for users bob and alice, so yes, it is a relative path (?).

Comment: It's an absolute path, even if it's a different one for different users. I could also write `/home/$SOMETHING/more/path`, and the expansion depends on my environment but **it expands to an absolute path.**

Comment: @anneb: "relative" in this context has a specific technical meaning, which is "relative to the CWD of the process".  Using other meanings of the English word "relative" is confusing.  (See [my answer on the linked duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222076/79808))

Comment: @Peter Cordes. I would agree if there would be a clear and single technical definition of 'relative path'. One such definition is [the Posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324). That definition does not mention relativity to the cwd specifically. Therefore we should prefer Engilish to the specs?

Comment: @anneb: interesting point.  I guess I'd say that definition needs to be applied to the path proper, which is the result of tilde-expansion on `~/Mary`.  Unless you use it in a context which doesn't do tilde-expansion, or if `$HOME=.`.  So POSIX doesn't mess around trying to describe `~/Mary` at all, and the most accurate (but less useful) thing to say is that what most people mean when they say `~/Mary` isn't actually a path yet.  But yes if you did use it as a path (without expansion), it would be relative.

Answer (score 4):

The two most highly voted answers (EightBitTony and Stéphane) are correct: `~` is a shell alias that [expands to the current user’s home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146697).

On every Unix-like system, the users’ home directories are specified as *absolute paths* in the user database (e.g., `/etc/passwd` is traditionally used for local user accounts).

However, some of the answers and comments seem confused as to the definition of the terms *absolute* and *relative* – with some bordering on a post-modern interpretation that all paths are relative (to their parent directory or to `/`).

---

#### Definitions from the POSIX specifications

To provide some clarity, I figured it would be useful to add an answer that quotes the definitions as specified by *The Open Group* in **POSIX.1-2008** (the definitions are linked to in Stéphane’s answer but not everybody follows the links):

A [pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271) is specified as

> A string that is used to identify a file.

An [absolute pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_02) is specified as:

> A pathname beginning with a single or more than two `<slash>` characters

A [relative pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324) is specified as

> A pathname not beginning with a `<slash>` character.

Also, how a *POSIX shell* expands the `~` is specified in [Tilde Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ~/Mary is a relative path.

This question seems to be a question of definition. I am not sure if there exists an official systems wide definition for *absolute path* and *relative path*

There are two types of 'path': *relative* and *absolute*. An absolute path always points to the same resource. Relative paths point to a resource relative to something else.

When ~ is used, it is normally used to be expanded to the current user home directory. The home directory depends on the current user, so ~/Mary is *relative* to the current user home directory.

For example `~/Mary` may expand to `/home/bob/Mary` for user bob and it may expand to `/home/alice/Mary` for user alice.

Some more examples
./Mary is relative to the current directory
../Mary is relative to the parent directory
~/Mary is relative to the current user home directory
Mary is relative to the current directory
/Mary is relative to the root directory. The root directory is fixed, so this is an absolute path

However, people might claim that even a root directory is relative to the current host. If you add a host to a path, it would become hostname:/Mary. But this is still not really an absolute path as 'hostname' is relative to the system that defines hostnames.

Comment: "The root directory is fixed" it isn't actually, but we mostly assume that it is.

Comment: Personally, I think relative is assumed to mean, relative to your current path when someone says 'a relative path'.  That of course is open to interpretation, but that's the beauty of language.  How about, `~/Mary` is an absolute path, the value of which can vary :)

Comment: And `$VAR/Mary` is relative to the content of the `$VAR` variable and `$(dirname -- "$0")/Mary` is relative to the output of tha `dirname` command.

Comment: You really think something as basic as relative and [absolute path](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_02) would have have "no official definition" after all these years of POSIX? That's wildly implausible (and wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a simple experiment:

```
[vttoth@host ~]$ cd /tmp
[vttoth@host tmp]$ mkdir "~"
[vttoth@host tmp]$ mkdir "~/Mary"
[vttoth@host tmp]$ ls -al "~"
total 12
drwxrwxr-x.  3 vttoth vttoth   17 Oct 12 20:24 .
drwxrwxrwt. 14 root   root   8192 Oct 12 20:24 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 vttoth vttoth    6 Oct 12 20:24 Mary
[vttoth@host tmp]$ cd "~/Mary"
[vttoth@host Mary]$ pwd
/tmp/~/Mary
```

Sure as heck looks relative to me.

However, if in the bash shell (same applies to many other shells) I do

```
[vttoth@host Mary]$ echo ~
/home/vttoth
```

it becomes evident that `~` is expanded by the shell into an absolute path.

In short, the question is ambiguous: the literal answer is that `"~/anything"` is a relative path, but one can guess that the question really is about how the shell expands the `~` symbol unless it is protected from expansion by the use of quotes.

I recommend reading the section titled tilde expansion in the bash man page, or the corresponding section(s) in the man pages of the preferred shell.